# Any tool to increment the build number and build version automatically for react-native apps (Both iOS and Android)

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to automate the build number and version for both **iOS and Android**.

For iOS there is agvtool and fastlane too.

Is there an alternate tool which will work seamlessly across iOS, Android

Answer (score 1):

So, I've been using a script in my build phases to increment the build number, but it only works if the value is specified in the `Info.plist` file, and not referenced in the `Info.plist` file. Given this was part of the 0.5x.x -> 0.6x.x change for React Native, it does mean I'm running in an old way.

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}" | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1/')
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```